# React input onChange did'nt fire on same value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, input

Code:

```
function SingleInput(props: {value: string; onChanged: (value: string) => void}) {
    const handleChange = useCallback(
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const newValue = e.target.value;
            console.log("onChange fired with value", newValue) /*FIXME Убрать!*/;
            props.onChanged(newValue);
        },
        [props.value, props.onChanged]
    );

    return <input type="text" maxLength={1} value={props.value} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

Problem:
Еhe `onChange` function is not called if I try to select an existing value and enter the same.

Example:
I type `1` on this component. Okay, onChange fired. Then I select this value by mouse and type `1` again - onChange didn't fired.

Question: What should I do so that the function is fired even on the same input?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `onInput` event. It will capture event even if you are adding same value.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Well, it works, but react controlled component should define onChange handler. If i add it with nop function - it works perfect. Thank you, and add as anawer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try with `onInput` event handler. It will capture event even if you are adding same value.

```
return <input type="text" maxLength={1} value={props.value} onChange={handleChange} onInput={handleChange} />;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to setup another state to store the all the uploaded files and clear the "onChange" - `props.onChanged("");`

i.e. like below so you can upload the same file and the actual file is located at "file"

```js
const [file, setFile] = useState("")
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")

<input 
  type="file" 
  value={inputValue} 
  onChange={(e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
    setInputValue("")
  }} 
/>
```